# Parallel lines in Omnigraffle

Tags: macos, mac, omnigraffle

In Omnigraffle, I need to connect two objects via two lines (not a bidirectional one) - way and back, to label each one differently. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two ways to do this<:

1. You need to add additional magnets to connect two lines in parallel. There should be two magnets at least on the other object to make separate the lines from each other.
2. If you only need curved lines from the same points you have to add mid points to one of the line at least and drag it apart from the other. This option does not require any additional magnets.